# Оператор эквивалентности <=>

Tags: c++, операторы, c++20

Увидел недавно оператор <=> в чужом коде и испытал культурный шок. Что за зверь, что он делает и когда использовать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <compare>


int main() {
    int a, b = a = 42;

    std::cout << (a <=> b == 0);
}
```

Comment: Ну, в стандарте такого нет, а вот что в этом `<compare>` - хотелось бы посмотреть...

Comment: @Harry этот оператор из С++20, насколько я помню.

Comment: @Harry пишет "превышение допустимой длины на 26599 символов", когда хочу добавить содержимое

Comment: @RiotBr3aker А! ну, я еще и С++17 не очень выучил :)

Comment: Если у кого появится желание перевести:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466358/what-is-the-operator-in-c

Answer (score 10):

Если вы когда либо писали операторы сравнения в более-менее тяжелых C++ классах, то вы, наверное, замечали, что вся идея построения системы сравнений вокруг классических операторов `<`, `>`, `==` и т.д. и/или вокруг соотношения "less" ("меньше"), на который опираются упорядочивающие алгоритмы стандартной библиотеки неудобна и дико неэффективна. Не существует приемлемого/эффективного способа реализации упорядочивающих соотношений для составных объектов на основе существующих соотношений для их индивидуальных компонентов.

Например, для класса

```
class Composite
{
  Type1 a;
  Type2 b;
  Type3 c;   
};
```

лексикографическое сравнение `<` будет выглядеть примерно так

```
bool operator <(const Composite &lhs, const Composite &rhs)
{
  if (lhs.a != rhs.a)
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
  if (lhs.b != rhs.b)
    return lhs.b < rhs.b;
  return lhs.c < rhs.c;
}
```

Это, разумеется, катастрофически плохо, ибо такой вариант на некотором шаге выполняет фактически одно и то же сравнение *два раза*. К примеру, сначала делается `lhs.a != rhs.a`, а затем `lhs.a < rhs.a`, то по сути является повторным выполнением одной и той же (возможно тяжелой) операции.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, в С++20 предложили новую парадигму реализации сравнений: в качестве основы выступают "трехсторонние" ("3-way") сравнения, хорошо знакомые нам еще из C. Теперь фундаментальным примитивом упорядочивающего сравнения для каждого типа данных будет оператор `<=>`, выполняющий трехстороннее сравнение. Все остальные виды сравнения будут неявно генерироваться на основе результата оператора `<=>`.

Например, на основе оператора `<=>` вышеприведенный скетч кода может быть переписан так

```
bool operator <(const Composite &lhs, const Composite &rhs)
{
  if (auto cmp = lhs.a <=> rhs.a; cmp != 0)
    return cmp < 0;
  if (auto cmp = lhs.b <=> rhs.b; cmp != 0)
    return cmp < 0;
  if (auto cmp = lhs.c <=> rhs.c; cmp != 0)
    return cmp < 0;
  return false;
}
```

(Пример приведен в иллюстративных целях. На самом деле правильнее будет реализовать именно и только оператор `<=>` для класса `Composite` и дать компилятору сгенерировать оператор `<` на его основе.)

Так что ответ на ваш вопрос про "когда использовать": никогда и всегда. В коде верхнего уровня он почти никогда не нужен. В вашем примере нет никакого повода использовать `<=>` вместо обычного `==`. А вот в качестве лежащей под всем этим основы для реализации операторов сравнения он нужен почти всегда. Без него вы просто не сможете построить приемлемой реализации лексикографического сравнения для составного объекта. В этой роли большинство из нас уже давно руками выписывали аналог этого оператора в виде какой-то функции. А теперь эта практика будет закреплена на уровне языка.

Также в стандартной библиотеке С++20 появится вспомогательная функция `std::compare_3way`, реализующая трехсторонние сравнения на базе обычных сравнений.

Answer (score 9):

Такой оператор известен как "**spaceship operator**" или космический корабль или оператор трехстороннего сравнения (так его официально называют), чаще всего я слышу первый вариант. Я этот оператор первый раз увидел на Perl и вроде как это был первый язык который использовал его, после чего он начал появляться в Ruby, PHP, C++ и т.д.

Этот оператор предназначен для сравнения двух выражений или значений. Запомнить как он работает, очень просто: Возвращается целочисленное значение -1, 0 или 1 если **a**, соответственно, меньше, равно или больше чем **b**. Все просто и очевидно, минус значит меньше, 0 значит нет разницы, 1 больше. Со стороны программного кода это эквивалент:

```
if a<b
  return -1
elsif a>b 
  return 1
else
  return 0
end
```

Набор таких возвращаемых значений уже давно известен, примерно с таким же успехом для строк работает функция **strcmp** или **memcmp**.

Очень удобно использовать данный оператор для реализаций всяких сортировок, ведь если писать какую-нибудь функцию сравнения и сортировки числового массива нужно 3 значения (больше, меньше, равно), так как значений bool (0,1) недостаточно.

Comment: Эм.. Это ж неправда... Даже про целочисленное значение - это всего лишь частный случай, а уж про -1, 0 и +1 - прям совсем частный-частный-частный.

Answer (score -7):

```
Это называется трехсторонним оператором сравнения.

Согласно предложению P0515:

Появился новый трехсторонний оператор сравнения <=>. Выражение a <=> b возвращает объект, который сравнивает <0, если a <b, сравнивает> 0, если a> b, и сравнивает == 0, если a и b равны / эквивалентны.

Чтобы написать все сравнения для вашего типа, просто напишите оператор <=>, который возвращает соответствующий тип категории:

Верните _ordering, если ваш тип естественным образом поддерживает <, и мы будем эффективно генерировать <,>, <=,> =, == и! =; в противном случае верните _equality, и мы будем эффективно генерировать == и! =.

Возвращает значение strong, если для вашего типа a == b подразумевает f (a) == f (b) (подстановочность, где f читает только состояние сравнения, доступное с использованием не частного интерфейса const), в противном случае возвращает значение слабое.

Совпадение говорит:

Выражения оператора трехстороннего сравнения имеют вид

lhs <=> rhs (1)
Выражение возвращает объект, который

сравнивает <0, если lhs <rhs
сравнивает> 0, если lhs> rhs
и сравнивает == 0, если lhs и rhs равны / эквивалентны.
```

Comment: Машинный перевод каждый может применить к оригиналу ответа. Может, сделаете его более "человеческим"? И не в вине выезжающих за пределы монитора :) строк? чай, не код...

Comment: Ничего не понял из ответа. Линк на оригинал пожалуйста.

Comment: @LLENN, под самим вопросом смотрите

Comment: Ну а что тут непонятно, написано же "возвращает объект, который сравнивает <0, если a <b, сравнивает> 0, если a> b, и сравнивает == 0, если a и b равны". В этом наборе слов заложен глубокий смысл, главное его увидеть, понять, и начать уже наконец использовать.