# автоматическая генерация некоторых операторов, имея в наличии противоположные

Tags: c++

Если в некотором классе определены операторы  `< ==`, что мешает компилятору  автоматически генерировать операторы `<=, >, >=, !=`? Насколько я помню, где то в стандартной библиотеке даже определены такие шаблонные операторы, а в стандартных итераторах определены все эти операторы как:

> если b < a, то   a > b, если !(b < a) то a >= b и так далее

Зачем это писать, если можно пользоваться общим шаблоном? И почему современные компиляторы не могут просто понять это,  зная что такое меньше и зная что такое равно?...

Comment: *"что мешает компилятору автоматически генерировать операторы"* Уже ничего, в С++20 примерно так и происходит (только вместо `< ==` нужны `<=> ==`). В подробностях сам еще не разобрался.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  вот я тоже  хочу разобраться, но С++20 не доступен на русском, а на английском мне будет очень трудно. Но вроде бы и до 17 компиляторы были достаточно умны для этого...

Comment: Ну, потому что упорядочение бывает всякое, бывает строгое, бывает не очень... Определите таким образом операторы для "нжницы-камень-бумага" :) *В общем случае* все совсем не так просто...

Comment: Операторы <, > перегружают не только для целей сравнения. Например, boost.spirit, (хотя его нельзя назвать удачным). Выведение нового оператора сравнения по существующим - все поломает в подобном коде.

Comment: @Chorkov, речь о шаблонных сравнениях, которые можно вывести по одному шаблону, имея меньше и равно

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1147685), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924245) .........................................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Если в некотором классе определены операторы  < ==, что мешает компилятору автоматически генерировать операторы <=, >, >=, !=?

Например, то, что логика класса может быть отлична от "человеческой логики". Как компилятор будет добавлять логику в ваш класс, если вы явно указали, что класс поддерживает только `<` и `==`? Изначально, такое поведение не предусмотрено языком, соответственно, нужно либо менять часть стандарта, отвечающее за это, что, возможно, поломает чей-то код, либо вводить какой-то дополнительный синтаксис, с помощью которого можно указать, что ваш класс действительно хочет, чтобы компилятор сделал эту работу для ваших операторов.

C++20 добавляет в язык новый оператор `<=>`, который предоставляет возможность реализовать т.н. "three-way сравнение". Данное сравнение давно представлено в C-функциях на подобии `strcmp`, которая возвращает значение меньше, равное или большее нуля в зависимости от лексикографического порядка значений аргументов. Для работы данного оператора введена новая механика, работающая для операторов отношения (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`), приблизительно, следующим образом:

- если пользователь определил свой `<=>`, и не определил какие-то операторы сравнения, то при использовании этих операторов, оператор `<=>` включается в список подходящих функций, причем, включая и обратный порядок операндов.
- если пользователь определил свой `<=>`, и определил какие-то операторы сравнения, то при использовании этих операторов будут использованы именно предоставленные пользователем перегрузки.

Если в результате разрешения перегрузки был выбран перегруженный оператор `<=>`, то выражение `x @ y`, где `@` - оператор сравнения, производится по правилу `(x <=> y) @ 0`, либо по правилу, `0 @ (y <=> x)` если порядок аргументов нужно инвертировать.

Разберем на примере перегрузку оператора `<=>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <compare>

struct Some
{    
};

bool operator>(Some const &, int)
{
    std::cout << "operator>(Some const &, int)" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

std::strong_ordering operator<=>(Some const &, Some const &)
{
    std::cout << "operator<=>(Some const &, Some const &)" << std::endl;
    return std::strong_ordering::less;
}

std::strong_ordering operator<=>(Some const &, int)
{
    std::cout << "operator<=>(Some const &, int)" << std::endl;
    return std::strong_ordering::less;
}

int main() 
{
    Some s1, s2;
    s1 < s2; //operator<=>(Some const &, Some const &)
    s1 > 2;  //operator>(Some const &, int)
    s1 < 2;  //operator<=>(Some const &, int)
    2 < s1;  //operator<=>(Some const &, int)
    2 > s1;  //operator<=>(Some const &, int)
}
```

Для типа `Some` предоставлено три оператора сравнения.

`s1 < s2` - будет сравниваться с помощью `operator<=>(Some const &, Some const &)` по правилу `(s1 <=> s2) < 0`. Результат, естевственно, `true`, т.к. наши операторы `<=>` не производят сравнения, а просто всегда считают, что первый аргумент меньше второго (возвращают `std::strong_ordering::less`).

В выражении `s1 > 2` будет использован перегруженный `operator>(Some const &, int)`.

В выражении `s1 < 2` будет выбран `operator<=>(Some const &, int)` и сравнение будет происходить по правилу `(s1 <=> 2) < 0`.

В выражении `2 < s1` также будет выбран `operator<=>(Some const &, int)`, но для его выбора необходимо инвертировать порядок аргументов и сравнение уже будет происходить по правилу `0 < (s1 <=> 2)`.

В выражении `2 > s1` также будет выбран `operator<=>(Some const &, int)` и сравнение будет происходить по правилу `0 > (s1 <=> 2)`.Заметьте, перегруженный пользователем `operator>(Some const &, int)` выбран не будет, т.к. для "старых" (two-way comparation) операторов инвертирование порядка аргументов не предусмотрено.

Таким образом, начиная с C++20, в классе достаточно будет перегрузить один оператор `<=>`, и, используя его, компилятор будет строить код для других сравнений, перегрузки операторов которых пользователь не предоставил.

Также необходимо будет предоставить оператор `==` для нужного типа аргументов, тогда компилятор будет генерировать на основе `==` оператор `!=`.

Подробнее об этом можете почитать на странице https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison
в секции "Three-way comparison".

Comment: Ну какие вопросы после такого ответа?... Все понял, спасибо.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я там подправил, уточнив по операторам отношения и равенства, ну и, конечно же, это C++, поэтому всего не опишешь. )))

Comment: Это еще один повод начинать осваивать  C++20,  самое главное, что  мне понятен был ответ на мой вопрос даже без поправок.  Этот ответ пойдет в избранные мной..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan к слову, clang 9 не собирает код `s1 >= 2` , но clang 10 уже собирает.

Comment: ну раз C++20,  значит наверняка так...

Answer (score -1):

Уже ничего, в С++20 примерно так и происходит (только вместо `< ==` нужны `<=> ==`).

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138402/Почему-в-c20-убрали-оператор-у-stdbitset/1147685#1147685](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138402/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-c20-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%83-stdbitset/1147685#1147685)

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924217/Оператор-эквивалентности/924245#924245](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924217/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/924245#924245)

Comment: не копируйте, пожалуйста, подчистую весь текст комментария. Если считаете комментарий полезный, то проголосуйте за него, либо же внесите в ответ хоть что-то от себя